# mapping a function to a list in Haskell 2 elements a time

Tags: haskell

I am trying a few problems (at [Spoj](http://www.spoj.pl/)) in Haskell and I have stumbled on quite a few which have input of the form:

```
testcase_1
testcase_1_continued
testcase_2 
testcase_2_continued
```

or

```
testcase_1 testcase_1_continued
...
```

As you can see, one cannot solve this by just using `words` or `lines` on the input and then mapping the solver function to get something like

```
[solver test1, solver test2, ...]
```

One should use a function with **two** arguements, which are two list elements, one after the other, and get:

```
[solver test1 test1continued, solver test2 test2continued, ...]
```

So I would be pleased to find an analogous function to `map` which applies a function 2 arguments at a time.I have not been able to find anything on Hoogle, and however easy it would be to write such a function, I am looking for a more general approach to the problem.Or, if my approach(of insisting on `map`) is definitely wrong, one could also point me to the right direction.

### Edit:

I actually found it really useful to implement a function map2 which maps a function to a list, only it works two arguments a time:

```
map2 f [a,b,c,d] ==> [f a b, f c d]
```

Comment: Idiomatic Haskell is to use `zipWith` and zip along the list and the tail of same list (which is one element shorter). Arguably Data.List should have a function for doing this directly but Data.List is quite big already.

Comment: @stephentetley: That will give you overlapping pairs of adjacent elements e.g. `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), ...]` while if I understood the OP correctly, he wants them non-overlapping, e.g. `[(1, 2), (3, 4), ...]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [chunksOf](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split-Internals.html#v:chunksOf).

```
> map (\[x, y] -> x + y) . chunksOf 2 $ [1..30]
[3,7,11,15,19,23,27,31,35,39,43,47,51,55,59]
```

Comment: Note that if the list has an odd number of elements this will cause a pattern match failure on the last element. The similar `[x + y | [x, y] <- chunk 2 [1..29]]` will truncate the list instead.

Comment: @hammar spoj is supposed to give only valid test cases.

Comment: Wow, this is a function really well buried into a haskell module!

Comment: Updated the answer to use `chunksOf`. `chunk` is deprecated.

Comment: Just to clarify: `chunk` is deprecated due to mailing list bikeshedding, not due to any intention of removing it. So choose `chunksOf` or `chunk` to please your own aesthetics.

Comment: @DanielWagner, it seems to be well and truly gone now.

Answer (score 3):

`map` is a great way to go, and if your data is structured like that, you might want to alter it slightly to fit the semantics better. One way to do that would be to "pair up" the result of `lines` so that you get `[(line1, line2),(line3, line4),...]`. The first argument of map will then be a function that works on these tuples.

**Edit:**
To expand on that, the general approach is then to read the input, format it into a semantically meaningful format, then either map or fold your solving function over the result. The exact solution depends on the input data.